# Get all content on a "single page" site depending on language

Tags: wp-query, plugin-wpml

I'm developing a "single page" WordPress based site that has content in multiple languages (using the plug-in WPML) and I need to retrieve it in a more efficient manner to avoid slow page load time.
An example of the code that I'm currently using -

```
$query = new WP_Query();
$query->query( array( 'post_type' => 'any', 'orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();

    // Gather the content for the first section of the page
    if( $post->ID == 100 ) {
        $firstSection .= get_content();
    }

    // Gather next content section etc...

}
```

Essentially, what I'm doing right now is looping through all posts looking for a specific ID, for which I then retrieve content tied to a certain part of the page. As you may understand, this gets quite messy after a while, having to create an if statement for each section content for each language. I have around 20 statements inside the while loop currently and I'm sure there is a better way to retrieve the data. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

WPML has a global to check for the language, though it might be outside the scope of WPSE because this is a commercial plugin.

It works like:

```
if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'){
//do something like a custom query...
}else{
// do something else
```

Comment: In reply to both of you - Perhaps a setup like this: 1. Check the current language 2. Query only the posts from that language (how?) 3. Loop through the query, now there's no need for "double if statements" (2 languages).

Comment: Put the query in the conditional language check, which is the example above..

Comment: Done. Clueless as of how to fetch all posts that are of a specific language via a query though (and with WPML specifically).

Comment: There is a query parameter for this documented on the WPML site, but since this is a commercial plugin we tend to close these questions here on stack, it's best if you ask over on their site.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I have put up a request at their support but it's not the fastest forum.
Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Have a decent look at wp_query.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

you can just filter on your post_id at hand. and get only that post.
crazy to go like you are doing :)

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'p=100' );
```

also

```
post_in
```

---

More on you question:
Using `Switch Case` will be better than your if statements.
You could nest them.
first switch case your language, then loop your pages.

Comment: Hm, not sure I understand - why would I want to make a query for every post when I can query them all and loop that query one single time?

Comment: then I do not quite understand your question I think.

Comment: I have a number of posts that I all need to retrieve because the site is a "single page" solution. I figure I can make a query that selects all, then loop through that query and assign a particular ID's content to a variable, which I print in between my HTML (in the example above, $firstSection). Now I manage to solve this, but I'd like to find out if there is a more efficient way of doing this than involving a severe amount of if statements.

Comment: using a switch might be a bit more efficient. 
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php  also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/427760/when-to-use-if-else-if-else-over-switch-statments-and-vice-versa

Comment: Yes, that might improve the script a bit. I'm more considered how to first check for language, then for the post ID. Not needing to do a language check every time I make a statement, if possible. That would cut down the size significantly.

Comment: can you maybe post the rest of your code? It is not clear, how you check for your language. Ofcourse you should not check this everytime. You could nest 2 switch cases. first language, outside your loop, then pages inside your loop.